# pesquisa condicional em PHP usando codeigniter

Tags: array, codeigniter, algoritmo-de-busca, condição

Tenho essa tabela na minha base de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso selecionar todos produtos pertencentes a uma marca, mas se o código dos produtos for o mesmo não deverá repetir o produto, deve usar o mesmo produto.
Exemplo, ao selecionar Toyota pretendo ter o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o meu controller seleciona todos produtos repetindo os nomes

```
$marca = $this->input->post('marca');
$query = array();

if (count($marca) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($marca as $row) {
        $i++;

        if ($row !== "") {
            if ($row !== "0") {
                $query[] = $marca;
                $this->db->where_in('marca', $query);

            } 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!

**1°)** A sua tabela "Produto" está com produtos idênticos duplicados. Ou seja, se você tivesse 20 mil canetas azuis Bic, não deve existir 20 mil registros com a mesma coisa "canetas azuis Bic". Por exemplo, existem 2 registros de mesmo nome "Roda", marca "Toyota" e código "0001". O correto é possuir uma coluna "quantidade" ao invés da duplicação do produto.

**2°)** A coluna "Marca" na tabela "Produto" está desnormalizada. Ou seja, deveria existir uma tabela "Marca" com colunas "código" e "nome da marca", e na tabela "Produto" apenas o código da marca, sem nome. E é em cima desta implementação que a resposta abaixo se assenta.

**3°)** A coluna "produto" da tabela "Produto" deveria se chamar "nome". E é em cima desta implementação que a resposta abaixo se assenta.

**4°)** Avaliar `count($marca) > 0` é incorreto porque `$marca` não é um `array`, mas é uma string vindo de um post.

O solicitado pela pergunta é uma questão a ser resolvida no model. No controller é preciso apenas sanitizar o código da marca antes de repassar ao model.

No controller:

```
<?php
    ...
    $id_marca = intval($this->input->post('marca'));
    $array_produtos = this->produto_model->get_produtos_by_marca($id_marca);
    // Só para visualizar o retorno
    print_r($array_produtos);
    ...
?>
```

E no model você faz o filtro:

```
<?php
    ...
    public function get_produtos_by_marca($id_marca) {
        $this->db->select('produto_id, nome');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('produto',  array('id_marca' => $id_marca));
        // Ou volta um array com resultados ou um array vazio
        return $query->num_rows() ? $query->result_array() : array();
    }
    ...
?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, O produto aparece duplicado porque, um produto pode pertencer a várias marcas e por sua vez a marca pode ter vários modelos. essa é a razão da duplicação dosvalores...